# Collect the column name whose value is True for each row in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
**col_A col_B col_C**
False True  False
True  False False
False False True
False False False
```

I need to collect the column name whose value is True for each row and create another dataframe:

```
**col**
col_B
col_A
col_C
nan
```

**Note**: there is at most one True value in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with `idxmax` and `where`:

```
df.idxmax(1).where(df.any(1))
```

Output:

```
0    col_B
1    col_A
2    col_C
3      NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your quick answer!